# Can sound waves be reflected/absorbed using a microwave-oven type mesh?

Tags: waves, acoustics

The mesh on a microwave is conducting and therefore acts as a Faraday cage if the mesh's holes are smaller than the wavelength of microwaves. My question is whether a similar effect can be achieved for sound. Say, I construct a cage similar to the one shown in the image, with sound absorbing walls and a mesh at the open end such that its holes are smaller than the wavelength of sound being stopped. Would the mesh prevent sound from exiting the cage, and if so, how effective would this be and what would be the intensity of sound emerging the other side?

Also, would the mesh material need to be sound absorbing or reflecting?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a Faraday cage to work, not only should the holes be small, but the cage material must also be electrically conductive. An acoustic analog for an electrical conductor is difficult to defin. Air as an acoustic medium is analogous to a dielectric in that waves can propagate through it, but it is also analogous to a conductor in that a static pressure gradient will lead to a net mass flow. But you can't build a mesh out of air.

EM waves are transversal, whereas acoustic waves are longitudinal. Transversal electric fields in an EM wave can generate oscillating electrical currents in the cage mesh, which in turn generates radiate an EM field that cancels the incoming field. But moving mass doesn't radiate acoustic waves; it's the moving interface between the mass and the air where acoustic radiation is generated.

So, no, there is no Faraday-cage equivalent for acoustic waves. But it's probably possible to design a hole pattern in a slab of stiff material that will not transmit plane sound waves at normal incidence by having different holes radiate in counterphase.

Answer (score 0):

Acoustic waves are mechanical, not electromagnetic. Acoustic waves propagate as standing waves of pressure through a transfer medium. Both wave types can travel radially in 3 dimensions. The acoustic waves look a series of spherical shells traveling outward.. I think of EM radiation as helical traveling exchanges from magnetic to electric back to magnetic and so on.